# Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI intellisense doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, intellisense, telerik-mvc, nopcommerce

I have a `Class Library` plugin for nopCommerce that acts like a MVC3 application and in the `Index.cshtml` I want to use the `Html.Telerik().Grid<MyModel>(Model)` and added in my `Index.cshtml` this `@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI` and it points that it's not found, but when I run the application I don't get an error saying that I don't have the references for that library and compiles my code fine, but I don't have intellisense for the `Telerik` library, also I added `<add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />` in my root `web.config` `Class Library` project and still don't have intellisense.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to resolve the issue:
1. using `gacutil.exe` to install the assembly in `cmd` like this `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64>gacutil.exe /i Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll`
2. finding the the PublickKeyToken for the assembly in `cmd` with `gacutil.exe` like this `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64>gacutil.exe /l Telerik.Web.Mvc` 
3. adding in my `Class Library` project web.config file the assembly like this:

```
 <add assembly="Telerik.Web.Mvc, Version=2012.1.214.340, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
```

4. adding the namespace in the web.config like this:

```
                <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

5. save, build, close visual studio, open again

Comment: You shouldn't have to install the Telerik libraries in the GAC.  I think there is something misconfigured in your environment.  Drop a message in the Telerik forums at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc.aspx for more help.